# Crystal Reports Texto lateral a través de varias secciones?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Estoy haciendo un report bastante normalito: cabecera, detalles y pié. El problema es que se necesita añadir un texto de información legal que tiene que ir en el lateral, a la altura de la sección detalles (cuadro rojo)

[image: vista del esquema del report]

Al añadirla en la sección detalles, obviamente me cambia la altura de cada registro.

He probado a ponerlo en las otras secciones y activar la opción "situar debajo de las secciones siguientes" el texto/imagen no se pone por debajo de las secciones siguientes.

No sé si sería más fácil hacerlo con una imagen, lo he intentado pero hace lo mismo, aumenta el tamaño de la sección.

¿Se puede hacer ésto?

Comment: ¿Alguna idea? ¿nadie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he resuelto le problema:

-Añadir sección en la cabecera de página
-Las secciones Quedan como: Cabecera del reporte, header(a) y header(b), detalles, pie del reporte, pie de página.
-Mantener los títulos del detalle en el header(a)
-Añadir la etiqueta de texto en formato vertical en el header(b)
-Ir al experto de secciones, seleccionar header (b) y marcar la opción "situar debajo de las secciones siguientes"

Solucionado. Por si le sirve a alguien :)

Comment: Guardaré esta respuesta ya que uno nunca sabe con que diseño de reporte se puede encontrar. Muchisimas gracias!!